# how to check whether c++ STL list is palindromic or not?

Tags: c++, stl

I want to check whether a given C++ STL list is palindromic or not?

```
bool isPalindromic(list <int> c);

int main(){

 list<int> l;
l.push_front(12);
l.push_front(35);
l.push_front(34);
l.push_front(35);
l.push_front(12);

isPalindromic(l);
}

output : true
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Had a think about it? Come up with any ideas? Done any research? SO is not a replacement for _thinking_! (That's why you're getting downvotes)

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 I thought about it like  while(!l.empty()){compare first and last element and if they are equal then pop both of them from list and if they are not equal return false }

Comment: Okay so that's fine for random access containers. Now have a think about how you'd do it when you can only go forwards and backwards at a time.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `std::equal` to check if list from the beginning is equal to the list from the end. cppreference page for [std::equal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) even has a example for that.

EDIT (as requested):
Basing on the example provided by cppreference:

```
std::equal(s.begin(), s.begin() + s.size()/2, s.rbegin());
```

The above line checks if a string is a palindrome. But in our case it will not work, since list's `begin()` returns `BidirectionalIterator`, and not the `RandomAccessIterator` string's `begin()` does, so we cannot do `s.begin() + s.size()/2` part. To make it work we should change our code to:

```
bool is_palindrome(const std::list<int>& l) //use templated version std::list<T> if needed
{
    return std::equal(l.begin(), l.end(), l.rbegin());
}
```

This of course is not perfect, since it iterates from the beginning to the end of the list, while it could just end after the middle, but it is simple and it works.

Comment: This answer would be even better if you could show how to call it.

Comment: @NathanOliver Edited the answer as requested.

Comment: Awesome.  FWIW You can use `return std::equal(l.begin(), std::next(l.begin(), l.size() / 2), l.rbegin());` to only check half of the list.

Comment: @NathanOliver -- that's true as far as it goes, but finding the middle of the list is also O(n), so if incrementing an iterator has a cost comparable to a comparison you really haven't gained anything; you're doing n/2 extra increments to avoid n/2 redundant comparisons. If comparisons are significantly more expensive than increments then finding the middle could be faster. On the other hand, if the first element doesn't equal the last element, finding the middle is just wasted time; the first comparison will determine the result regardless of the termination condition.

Answer (score 2):

Palindrome means "the same read forwards and backwards", so just compare `c` with `std::reverse(c)`.

Comment: how to compare two STL lists?

Comment: @TejasJadhav `first_list == second_list` comes to mind. ;)

Comment: @DeiDei I guess we have to overload operator== for that

Comment: That seems really heavy weight when reverse iterators are a thing...

Comment: @Shawn there are many ways to do it. Most of the time it doesn't matter which one you pick, so I picked the simplest one.

Comment: Not a fan of this.  This requires a full copy plus N/2 swaps which is going to be very inefficient.  And then there is the comparisons which is another O(N) operation.

Comment: @NathanOliver In most situations it won't make one iota of difference, so I just picked the simplest option.

Comment: @TejasJadhav No you don't need to overload the operator. `std::list` already provides one.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I think it's best to teach people from the outset to at least be mindful of those kinds of considerations. Too much software out there nowadays that doesn't give a crap about memory usage and uses _far too much_ as a result. That's not premature optimisation: it's writing the appropriate code for the job. And, after all, we _are_ teaching here. :)

Comment: @Lightness I respectfully disagree.

Comment: @JesperJuhl You think we should not teach people to write the appropriate code for the job and use the appropriate amount of memory? Okay we'll agree to disagree then.

Comment: @Lightness Of course we should try to teach the best we can. But sometimes performance matters less than code readability or other things.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution that avoids unnecessary comparisons performed by `std::equal(begin, end, rbegin)`:

```
template<typename T>
bool is_palindrome(const std::list<T>& list) {
    auto it1 = list.begin();
    auto it2 = list.end();
    if (list.size() % 2 == 0) {
        while (it1 != it2)
            if (!(*it1++ == *--it2))
                return false;
    } else {
        while (it1 != --it2)
            if (!(*it1++ == *it2))
                return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note that since C++11 [`std::list::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/size) has constant time complexity.

Example:

```
std::list<int> l{12, 35, 34, 35, 12};
std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_palindrome(l);   // Output: true
```

[Demo with basic test cases](https://godbolt.org/z/vNNKj_)